# Kentico starting and debugging a website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, content-management-system, kentico

so i'm starting a hopefully not to long period of CMS development, a website created with kentico and based on web pages (.aspx) (never worked with any CMS or web pages so i'm an entry level on all aspects).

I have a production copy of this website on my local PC.
Also i have a local copy of the DB instance from production.

Website Structure looks like this:

1 Solution with 1 folder Lib and 1 website called CMS.

I've changed the connection string so that it will point to my local db instance.

Now I'm just trying to run the website in debug mode (F5) so that i can see what is going on. What i was expecting was to enter a website (the one which is in production) but from localhost. Imagine the build in MVC app provided by visual studio.

I hit F5 this is what i get[image]

Have no idea what just happened, why i don't see the website content ??

Moving on,, I hit the Sites and was expecting to lunch my website at this point but i'm redirected to a different page a configuration page,   [image]

here i see the production website name with its domain. Why?

So what i basically want to achieve, like said earlier, I just want to run this website as a normal MVC application when i hit F5 i enter debug mode on my localhost, and i see the home page content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Sites Application (second screen), edit your website record (press pencil button in grid), go to Domain Aliases tab, enter new domain alias record by localhost. You also should do have licence key for localhost to make it work.

Also you can deploy your app on local IIS service, and use Debug->Attach to process in Visual Studio.

Comment: Also make sure debug flag is set to "True" in web.config